Why does my Android release APK show a white screen while the debug APK works fine?
I am developing an Android application that plays media using ExoPlayer, and I am facing an issue with my release APK.
When I install the release version of my APK, it only shows a white screen. However, the debug version works perfectly.
   buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release // Correct usage
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

here this is my build.gradle
I have tried enabling debugging in the release build, but it still shows a white screen,
What could be causing the release version of my APK to display a white screen, and how can I fix this issue?

Do you means implement exoplayer is used androidx/media?

I bet your ProGuard rules are stripping out something important.  Do you have serialization in your app?
